Troubles on Kubuntu 20.04 with touchpad
2 days ago I downloaded Kubuntu 20.04 on my MEGABOOK L740 ( it's old asf ). So, my touch-pad haves a problem wit left button, I changed in "touch-pad settings" like I'm left-handed and now my right button works like it's left. How can I enable left button? If it's trouble with driver, how can I find drivers list?
Also when I do double touch on the sensor-place it doesn't want to work. Help pls

Does the left button on the touchpad not work at all? Are you sure it is not a hardware issue?

yesterday I aggressively touched the left button and it works, but only after few milliseconds

Can you try booting a different version of Ubuntu? (if it is old, try Xubuntu instead, maybe 24.04). If the problem persists, it may really be a hardware issue
